# Why isn't `tail -f … | grep -q …` quitting when it finds a match?

Tags: linux, grep, tail

I'm doing a pretty standard `tail` + `grep`:

```
tail -f some_log_file.txt | grep -q known-string
```

If I run the command without the `-q`:

```
tail -f some_log_file.txt | grep known-string
```

I see output:

```
[Tue Feb 12 11:32:45 2019] known-string.
```

so I know the grep is matching.  However when I add `-q` the grep command doesn't exit, it just hangs there waiting for more output ... even though the man page says it will "Exit immediately  with  zero status if any match is found":

> ```
>    -q, --quiet, --silent
>           Quiet;  do  not  write  anything  to  standard   output.    Exit
>           immediately  with  zero status if any match is found, even if an
>           error was detected.  Also see the -s or --no-messages option.
> ```

Can anyone explain why `-q` isn't causing my grep to exit?  I'm trying to chain a `&& beep` to the end so the `grep` beeps when a match is found, but unless I can make it exit that won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From StackOverflow post
['grep -q' not exiting with 'tail -f'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178888/grep-q-not-exiting-with-tail-f):

> `tail -f` will read a file and display lines later added, it will not
>   terminate (unless a signal like `SIGTERM` is sent). `grep` is not the
>   blocking part here, `tail -f` is. `grep` will read from the pipe until
>   it is closed, but it never is because `tail -f` does not quit and keep
>   the pipe open.
>
> ---
>
> A solution to your problem would probably be (not tested and very
>   likely to perform badly):
>
> ```
> tail -f logfile | while read line; do
>   echo $line | grep -q 'find me to quit' && break;
> done
> ```

You will find more information and solutions in the linked post.

Answer (score 7):

`grep` does exit and the pipe goes away, although `tail` keeps running. [This bug report log](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13183) starts with a use case very similar to yours:

> I want to use `tail` and `grep` to follow a file until a particular pattern appears. But `tail` does not exit when `grep` is finished.
>
> ```
> $ echo xxx > /tmp/blabla
> $ tail -f /tmp/blabla |grep -m1 --line-buffered "xxx"
> xxx
> ```
>
> Now `tail` still tries to read and exits only if I write again into `/tmp/blabla`.
>
> Is this how it's supposed to be?

The explanation there:

> `tail` does exit on SIGPIPE, however it will only get the signal on `write()`, and so you need to get more data in the file before `tail` will exit.

As far as I know, this exact mechanism is very common. Many tools exit *after* they try to write something to a broken pipe, it's not a bug.

Then this wish came:

> It's a fair point though that `tail`, since it can hang around forever should take special steps to be responsive to the other end of the pipe going away.

And finally:

> Implemented in:
> https://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=v8.27-42-gce0415f

And indeed, when I try to reproduce your problem with `tail` from GNU coreutils 8.28, I cannot. The tool exits immediately.