# How to exit `sed` after the first match?

Tags: linux, regex, sed

I need to search a pattern `I/f` in a file between some range of lines and quit on the first match. For that I am using sed command like this

```
sed -n '14922,28875{\|I/f|=}' file.txt
```

It actually prints all the occurence between line 14922 to 28875 but I want only first occurence.

I have one alternate solution for this which is to pipe line the output and use head command. Something like that

```
sed -n '14922,28875{\|I/f|=}' file.txt | head -n 1
```

It works but just wondering if it is possible without head command. I searched on the internet and I found we use `q` character but somehow I am not getting right place to insert that in my command. Can anyone please help me in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{=;q}` instead of `=`:

```
sed -n '14922,28875{\|I/f|{=;q}}' file.txt
```

If there is no match, `sed` will keep reading the file without a chance of producing any output. This is sub-optimal. Make it quit after processing the 28875th line:

```
sed -n '14922,28875{\|I/f|{=;q}};28875q' file.txt
```

---

Note in your example with `head -n 1`, if `head` does its job and exits then `sed` will notice this only when it tries to write a second line to its stdout (compare [this](https://superuser.com/a/1405010/432690)). This means `sed` will keep processing the file until the second match is found or till the end. In this aspect it's even worse than my sub-optimal solution with `q`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. the solution u suggested is working `sed -n '14922,28875{\|I/f|{=;q}}' file.txt` but the second command `sed -n '14922,28875{\|I/f|{=;q}}28875q' file.txt` gives an error

Comment: @vivek What is the error exactly?

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 25: extra characters after command

Comment: @vivek Try the current version where everything is in one line.

Comment: Yes it is working fine. Thank you very much

Comment: I have one more question posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1555232/sed-perform-pattern-search-in-reverse-order-in-a-certain-range-and-get-the-line). Can you please have a look on it

Comment: Can you remind us what `=` does on its own, and `q` on its own, as part of this answer?