# Sed: Perform pattern search in reverse order in a certain range and get the line number on each match

Tags: linux, regex, sed

I want to search the pattern in a certain range but in reverse order. For example if I give the range say 200,250 then I want that search should be performed in reverse order means search should start from line number 250 and if any line matche the pattern  then print the line number

I have tried this command `sed -n '!G;h;200,250{\|perl: warning:|=}' a.txt` but it actually perform the search in ascending order

I have searched on internet and found if we do `sed '1!G;h;$!d' a.txt` then it actually print the file in reverse order. Just want to modify this command such that it print the line number in reverse order on each pattern match.

So How can I modify the command. Please help

Comment: Can't you just run normal search and then `tac` the output?

Comment: @choroba yes we can do it. But just wondering if it is possible with sed then it will be more good to me. Do you have any idea on it