# How to limit text output of iftop?

Tags: iftop

How to tell the tool `iftop` to print once a snapshot of active connections without cycling while in text mode?

```
iftop -t -i  eth2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to *tell* `iftop -t` to print one chunk and not to loop.

For comparison: `top -b -n 1` can do what you want, the relevant option is `-n 1`. It's a different tool, but this example shows how easy it can be when the tool supports the option (note: `iftop` understands `-n` but it's a *different*, unrelated option).

Still you can parse the output and stop after the first chunk. In my Debian 10 `iftop -t` terminates each chunk with a line consisting of many `=` characters. It seems `^==` is a good regex to detect the end of a chunk without false positives.

This command exits after the first chunk:

```
iftop -t -i eth2 | sed '/^==/ q'
```

Alternatively:

```
iftop -t -i eth2 | awk '{print; if ($0 ~ "^==") exit}'
```

To exit after the Nth chunk we need more complex code. In the following example N is 3. Adjust `n=3` to your needs:

```
iftop -t -i eth2 | awk -v n=3 '
   BEGIN {if (n<=0) exit}
   {
       print
       if ($0 ~ "^==") n--
       if (n<=0) exit
   }'
```

Notes:

- When `awk` (or `sed`) exits, `iftop` is not notified immediately. It gets `SIGPIPE` only when it tries to write something more to the now broken pipe. This means the whole command will stall until `iftop`  generates yet another chunk (which will not be printed). This is normal. Optimizing `iftop` in this matter makes little sense, it's not like it's going to stall forever. Compare [how it makes sense for `tail`](https://superuser.com/a/1405010/432690).
- If the whole command prints to the console, you may see the output pauses mid-chunk. This behavior is different than of the output from sole `iftop -t` where full chunks appear with pauses in between. The buffering between `iftop` and `awk` is to blame. In my tests [`stdbuf -oL iftop …`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97294/108618) helped.
- `iftop` prints some messages to stderr. They will not go through the pipe, unless you use `iftop … 2>&1 | …`.